# TypeError in view: Field expected a number but got ' '

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

it's my first time posting a question in stack overflow so bear with me :D
I'm trying to create a staff model from a form but an error keep persisting

This is my models file :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "HOD"), (2, "Consultant"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)


class Consultant(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'au paiement'),
        ('J15', 'J+15'),
        ('J30', 'J+30'),
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_id=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    tarif_facturation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tarif_Consultant = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cnss = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rib = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    paiement = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=CHOICES)
    profile_pic = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

@receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 1:
            AdminHOD.objects.create(admin=instance)
        if instance.user_type == 2:
            Consultant.objects.create(admin=instance, client_id=Client.objects.get(id=1), tarif_Consultant="", tarif_facturation="", cnss="", rib="", paiement="")


@receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
def save_user_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if instance.user_type==1:
        instance.adminhod.save()
    if instance.user_type==2:
        instance.consultant.save()
```

My views:

```
def add_staff_save(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
    else:
        email=request.POST.get("email")
        password=request.POST.get("password")
        first_name=request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name=request.POST.get("last_name")
        username=request.POST.get("username")
        client_id=request.POST.get("client")
        tarif_facturation=request.POST.get("tarif_facturation")
        tarif_Consultant=request.POST.get("tarif_Consultant")
        cnss = request.POST.get("cnss")
        rib = request.POST.get("rib")
        paiement = request.POST.get("paiement")
        #try:
        user=CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,last_name=last_name,first_name=first_name,user_type=2)
        client_obj=Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
        user.consultants.client_id=client_obj
        user.consultant.tarif_facturation=tarif_facturation
        user.consultant.tarif_Consultant=tarif_Consultant
        user.consultant.cnss=cnss
        user.consultant.rib=rib
        user.consultant.paiement=paiement
        user.save()
```

Here is the Traceback :

```
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gestion']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'gestion.LoginCheckMiddleWare.LoginCheckMiddleWare']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  
File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)


  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)


  **File "C:\Users\WD\Desktop\weserveit\gestion\HodViews.py", line 95, in add_staff_save
    user=CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,last_name=last_name,first_name=first_name,user_type=2)**

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 146, in create_user
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 800, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 179, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 179, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

  **File "C:\Users\WD\Desktop\weserveit\gestion\models.py", line 134, in create_user_profile
    Consultant.objects.create(admin=instance, client_id=Client.objects.get(id=1), tarif_Consultant="", tarif_facturation="", cnss="", rib="", paiement="", profile_pic="")

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method**
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 789, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 892, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 932, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1394, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1339, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1339, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1338, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1279, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 818, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)

  File "C:\Users\WD\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1778, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
```

**Exception Type: ValueError at /add_staff_save
Exception Value: Field 'tarif_facturation' expected a number but got ''.**

Comment: Have you done any debugging? As an aside, are you using the base Conda environment for development?

Comment: yes i'm using conda.. thank you for the reply, markwalker_ solved the problem

Comment: _yes i'm using conda.._ Right, but are you using the **base** (/root, default) environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your creation of the `Conslutant` object in the `post_save`

```
Consultant.objects.create(
    admin=instance,
    client_id=Client.objects.get(id=1),
    tarif_Consultant="",
    tarif_facturation="",
    cnss="",
    rib="",
    paiement=""
)
```

`tarif_facturation` is an `IntegerField` but right there your value is an empty string. Make that value a number and that error will be resolved.

However you're doing the exact same thing for lots of those other attributes that you're setting in the `Consultant` creation, so just make sure your values match the types the model requires.

Something like this;

```
Consultant.objects.create(
    admin=instance,
    client_id=Client.objects.get(id=1),
    tarif_facturation=1,
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick reply .. I'm new to django can you show me how to do that properly ?

Comment: @aminezahhaoui I added an example to my answer